# Java FFmpeg no output

Tags: java, ffmpeg, processbuilder

I´ve run into problem. I want to convert video using ffmpeg but it gives me no output

```
public void convert(String inputFile, String outputFile, String ... optionalParams) {
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("ffmpeg", "-i", "\"" + inputFile.trim() +"\"", "\""+ outputFile.trim() + "\"");
    DownloadRecord downloadRecord = table.getItems().get(0);
    downloadRecord.setStatus("Downloading");
       // Try to execute process
       try {
           // Set the working directory
           processBuilder.directory(new File(workingDirectory));
           //Start the process
           Process process = processBuilder.start();

           // Read the output from cmd
           BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
           BufferedReader ra = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));

           String line;
           String errline;
           while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
           }

           while ((errline = ra.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(errline);
           }
           process.waitFor();
           System.out.println("the end");
       } catch(IOException | InterruptedException e) {
           System.out.println(e.toString());
       }
}
```

I've been searching on stackoverflow and find some solutions, none worked. What I tried and figured out so far

- No output or error output
- I tried to remove backslashes from ProcessBuilder, it
  also gives me no output
- I tried to let the program running, but it never finishes
- I tried to use full path to the ffmpeg, no changes
- I tried to run the video, no error
- I am using
  Netbeans IDE so I tried clean and rebuild project, no change
- process also never finishes

I would like from it an output. Does someone know what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: `BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));` are you sure you want the **input** stream?

Comment: Yeah :) I am using basically the same code on YoutubeDL and it works. I want to read the data from cmd so the input, I am not sending anything out.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by reinstalling the ffmpeg. Just went ffmpeg website downloaded newest version, replaced files in folder and it works

Edit:
It just works for files with less thatn 2 mins for some reason, more thatn 2 mins files are behaving like this
I start converting, it will not convert entirely until program runs. After I exit the program it will finish. It´s strange behaviour.